# Sweden: tax on sale of property?

Tags: relocation, sweden

I am an EU citizen and planning to move to Sweden and that includes buying an apartment in Stockholm. The question is, if for some reason i'll have to sell the apartment in the future, what taxes will apply to the sale?

Eg. lets say i purchase apartment for 3 million SEK and i'll sell it after 3-4 years for (presumably) the same amount of 3 million SEK. How is this taxed?

Answer (score 5):

You will pay 30% tax on 22/30 of the profit, so in practice 22% tax on the profit. No profit means no tax.

Cooperative flats are more than 99% of the market. More info about tax on cooperative flats here: [Skatteverket](https://www.skatteverket.se/servicelankar/otherlanguages/inenglish/individualsandemployees/declaringtaxesforindividuals/howtofileyourtaxreturn/thecontentsoftheincometaxreturn/saleofacooperativeflat.4.7be5268414bea064694c794.html)